# Scaled dpi bitmaps for various screen sizes' backgrounds

Tags: android, xml, bitmap, dpi

With Android's nine-patch generator (http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html), what resolution do you recommend for the base, xhdpi, to retrieve the other scaled dpi bitmaps if I wanted to fit a screen's background on devices ranging from Android wear to Nexus 5 to Android TV?

Are there any alternative ways for this **without** hardcoding certain dimension-sized png files for particular device screens?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best alternative is to use xml drawable, it fits great on all displays.
read more here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

Also, if you plan to make you app for android 5 or later then drawable vector is another great choice:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html

If non of these did the job for you I recommend you to make your resources for hdpi and xxhdpi, these tow should be scaled with no problems most of time.